# setting file format with find/execute command in bash

Tags: bash

I know you can set file format with `set ff=unix` in vi editor.

But is there a way to do the same with a `find -exec {} \;` command instead of opening the file in vi?

Comment: Generally speaking, this question is a better fit for [unix.se] than Stack Overflow, being more about using UNIX tools than about writing software.

Answer (score 0):

Running `:set fileformat=unix` in vim has the same effect as the (common, but not standardized) `dos2unix` command. Thus:

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} +
```